# Как узнать какая форма сейчас на переднем плане под курсором?

Tags: windows, delphi, vcl

Как узнать какая форма сейчас на переднем плане под курсором?
так верно будет или есть ситуации где это не будет работать?
может цикл с нуля начать.
не знаю в каком порядке в листе Screen.CustomForm хранятся формы

дополнение
Под курсором может быть что угодно на переднем плане.
Но надо найти форму своего приложения которая выше всех и под курсором.

```
function GetFormAtPointScreen:TCustomForm;
var P,P2:TPoint;
    R2:TRect;
    i:integer;
begin
    GetCursorPos(P);
    Result:=nil;
    for I := Screen.CustomFormCount-1 downto 0 do
    begin
       P2:=Screen.CustomForms[i].ClientOrigin;
       R2:=Screen.CustomForms[i].ClientRect;
       R2.Offset(P2);
       if R2.Contains(P) then
       begin
         Result:= Screen.CustomForms[i];
         break;
       end;
    end;

     //Screen.
end;
```

2. Как определить что FormDop Выше FormMain и наоборот
   если я захочу FormMain.FormStyle:= fsStayOnTop;

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока рещил так
вернуть список форм как они расположены по z координате

```
  {function Title(h:Cardinal):string;
 var str:array[0..256-1] of char;
 begin
  GetWindowText(h,@str,256);
  Result:=  str;
 end; }

 class function AmWinApiSup.GetListZForm():TArray<Cardinal>;
var Forms,ListZ:TList<Cardinal>;
  I: Integer;
  H: Cardinal;
  //s:string;
begin
    //  TArray [0] содержит handle самой высокой формы
    //  TArray [length-1] самой низкой
    // это вариант более гибче чем вернуть просто форму по координатам
    // после выполения можно добавить свои фильтры или что
    //  а сопоставить координаты мыши с handel
    //if GetWindowRect(TArray [i], Rect) then
    // Result := Rect.Contains(Point) true значит курсор под формой с этим ханделом


    SetLength(Result,0);
    if (Application=nil)
    or (Application.MainForm = nil)
    or not Application.MainForm.HandleAllocated  then
    exit;
    Forms:=TList<Cardinal>.Create;
    ListZ:=  TList<Cardinal>.Create;
    try
       for I := 0 to Screen.CustomFormCount-1 do
        if  Screen.CustomForms[i].HandleAllocated then
        Forms.Add( Screen.CustomForms[i].Handle);
        H:= Application.MainForm.Handle;

        if IsWindowVisible(h) and (Forms.IndexOf(h)>=0) then
        ListZ.Add(h);
        h :=GetWindow(h, GW_HWNDNEXT);
        while (h<>0) do
        begin
          h :=GetWindow(h, GW_HWNDNEXT);
          if IsWindowVisible(h) and (Forms.IndexOf(h)>=0) then
          ListZ.Add(h);
        end;
        H:= Application.MainForm.Handle;
        while (h<>0) do
        begin
          h :=GetWindow(h, GW_HWNDPREV);
          if IsWindowVisible(h) and (Forms.IndexOf(h)>=0) then
          ListZ.Insert(0,h);

        end;

       { for I := 0 to ListZ.Count-1 do
          begin
              S:=Title(ListZ[i]);
          end;  }
        SetLength(Result,ListZ.Count);
        TArray.Copy<Cardinal>(ListZ.List,Result,0,0,ListZ.Count);

    finally
      Forms.Free;
      ListZ.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: а если под курсором чужое окно - что выдавать тогда?

Comment: @kami хотелось бы пройтись по координате z и найти свое верхнее окно формы

Comment: тут дельфийская оболочка не поможет, она разработана с целью решения обычных "офисных" задач.. На уровне работы с  разборкой сообщений от мыши в Windows API или Computer Training API от мелкомягких - возможно, и то попотеть надо. ПО умолчанию даже упреждающие сообщения не проходят сквозь чужие окна, если они того не хотят, на уровне ОС.

Comment: @Swift - Friday Pie
ок а хотя бы для своего приложения как это реализовать? пропустим на чужие окна и остановимся на том что сейчас приложение на верхнем уровне находится

Answer (score 2):

Судя по исходному коду - вы используете не особо старую версию Delphi, посему - код создан с расчетом на наличие дженериков.
Вкратце:
требуется пройтись по z-координате окон (всех-всех, не только своих - иначе z-order не поймать, google by windows z-order enumerate), проверяя на вхождение координаты курсора границам окна, и как только итератор дойдет до окна, принадлежащего "нашему" приложению - задача выполнена.

```pascal
procedure FillHandles(OwnedFormHandles: TDictionary<THandle, TCustomForm>);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // здесь заполняем словарик, чтобы не пробегать на каждый чих по всем формам
  // и иметь очень быстрый доступ к окну по ключу.
  for i := 0 to Screen.CustomFormCount - 1 do
    if Screen.CustomForms[i].Visible then
      OwnedFormHandles.add(Screen.CustomForms[i].Handle, Screen.CustomForms[i]);
end;

function IsWindowHandleInPoint(Handle: THandle; Point: TPoint): Boolean;
var
  lpRect: TRect;
begin
  // надеюсь, что здесь комментарии излишни.
  if GetWindowRect(Handle, lpRect) then
    Result := lpRect.Contains(Point)
  else
    Result := False;
end;

function GetFormAtPointScreen: TCustomForm;
var
  OwnedFormHandles: TDictionary<THandle, TCustomForm>;
  Window: HWND;
  Point: TPoint;
begin
  GetCursorPos(Point);
  Result := nil;

  OwnedFormHandles := TDictionary<THandle, TCustomForm>.Create;
  try
    FillHandles(OwnedFormHandles); // заполним "реестр" наших окон

    Window := GetTopWindow(GetDesktopWindow());
    while Window <> 0 do // и пройдемся по всем
    begin
      if IsWindowHandleInPoint(Window, Point) then // в поиске вхождения координаты в границы окна
        if OwnedFormHandles.ContainsKey(Window) then // и принадлежания нашему приложению. 
                     //Для ускорения обработки условия следует поменять местами.
        begin
          Result := OwnedFormHandles[Window];
          break;
        end;

      Window := GetWindow(Window, GW_HWNDNEXT); // видимо не нашли - двигаемся дальше
    end;

  finally
    OwnedFormHandles.Free; // не забываем: "я тебя породил - я тебя и убью"
  end;
end;
```

Comment: ага спс. вот последний час сидел писал GetZFormList гляньте в вопросе дополнил

Comment: `писал GetZFormList` - есть замечания по реализации, но если работает и удовлетворяет поставленным условиям - то почему бы и да.

Comment: скажите замечания все хочу знать))